# How to fix "KeyError: 2" in for loop?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

When I try to populate my 3d array with a simple for loop, an error message pops up with "KeyError:2"

I've tried populating the 3d array manually, and it works fine. The one_hot_encode function returns an (96, 4) array.

```py
y = np.empty((len(train_dataset), 96, 4))
for i in range((len(train_dataset)):
    y[i]=one_hot_encode(train_dataset["sequence"][i])

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-178-ed7edfb23253> in <module>
      1 y = np.empty((len(train_dataset), 96, 4))
      2 for i in range(len(train_dataset)):
----> 3     y[i]=one_hot_encode(train_dataset["sequence"][i])

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/series.py in __getitem__(self, key)
   1062         key = com.apply_if_callable(key, self)
   1063         try:
-> 1064             result = self.index.get_value(self, key)
   1065 
   1066             if not is_scalar(result):

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py in get_value(self, series, key)
   4721         k = self._convert_scalar_indexer(k, kind="getitem")
   4722         try:
-> 4723             return self._engine.get_value(s, k, tz=getattr(series.dtype, "tz", None))
   4724         except KeyError as e1:
   4725             if len(self) > 0 and (self.holds_integer() or self.is_boolean()):

pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_value()

pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_value()

pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.Int64HashTable.get_item()

pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.Int64HashTable.get_item()

KeyError: 2
```

Comment: You need to be using the Pandas indexing tools, e.g. `.loc` and/or `.iloc` for `train_dataset["sequence"][i]`. See [the docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html)

Comment: The error means that either `y[2]` does not exist or `train_dataset["sequence"][i]` does not - hence the KeyError.

Comment: Many thanks! turned out my pandas dataframe didn't have 2 as index, hence the KeyError.